# Set Landscape Orientation for iPad Only NOT iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an iPhone Storyboard and iPad Storyboard in my xCode project. In my iPhone version, I only want portrait mode to work (which is already there).

Now, I have added a storyboard for iPad, but iPad is working only with Portrait mode. However, I want the iPad to work in Portrait and Landscape and the iPhone to remain as portrait only

Please advise.

Comment: It is too easy, you could have searched your own.
Do some effort before asking the question.
And i think, there are already answers available for this on stackoverflow.

any way I h'v put the answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Select your project -> Target -> Deployement info -> iPhone.
and checkmark as follow:

for iPhone:

[image: for iPhone]

And for iPad:

[image: for iPad]

Comment: it works, if you don't see iphone / ipad buttons just check this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/38325076/436085

Comment: 2021 and this doesn't work like this anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Select your Project from document directory.
Go to `Targets->General->Deployment Info`
Here you will have iPhone and iPad options with relevant orientation info.
Checkmark the orientations you want, specific to device.