# Objective C only portrait orientation in a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I need to have a ViewController only in portrait orientation. I tried use this code but it didn't work:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

I tried it too:

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    NSLog(@"Interface orientations %@", window);
    if(!enablePortrait)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

**AudioViewController.m**

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).enablePortrait= YES;
}
```

it works if initially the iPad was in portrait mode. But if the iPad was in landscape mode, when I go back to the previous viewController (AudioViewController.m) the viewController stays in landscape too.

I tried it too i viewWillAppear.m but no effect:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

Please help me!

Thank you for advance.

**EDIT**

**PROVISIONAL SOLUTION:**

Finally I do this: (It works for me, but I hope find a better solution)

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).enablePortrait= YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];

    UINavigationController* nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:nc animated:NO completion:^{
    }];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

Comment: Read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041650/ios7-ios6-conditional-rotation-portrait-landscape-for-different-sections-of

Comment: Regarding the content of the link, I don't understand where I have to push this code:  LandscapeViewController * viewController = [[[LandscapeViewController ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINib * nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NavigationController" bundle:nil];
NavigationController *navController = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[navController initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{
    // completion
}];

Comment: Have I to create a new ViewController named LandscapeViewController?

Comment: No. I think that should be a previous ViewController (the one you're pushing from)

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785766/set-landscape-orientation-for-ipad-only-not-iphone/20786308#20786308) might help you.

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785766/set-landscape-orientation-for-ipad-only-not-iphone/20786308#20786308>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I do this: (It works for me, but I hope find a better solution)

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).enablePortrait= YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];

    UINavigationController* nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:nc animated:NO completion:^{
    }];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this inside the APPDelegate class for make viewcontroller always in portrait:`- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}`

Comment: I tried this, and the error was: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'` when I push the landscape viewController

Comment: you just need to implement this method in AppDelegate.m and remove any other orientation method from view controller...if it's not working then please send me your block of code.

Comment: **AppDelegate.m**
`- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}`

**AudioViewController.m**
`- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

}`
And I delete other functions related with orientation...

Comment: create new demo application and use above function only in AppDelegate.m and after that you can use this to according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

And please make your supportedInterfaceOrientations method same. Let me know if that helps.. :)

Comment: Did you changed supportedInterfaceOrientations?

Comment: Sorry, I'll change it

Comment: I can't change supportedInterfaceOrientation because I received a UIWindow *window not a ViewController to get de interfaceOrientation...

Comment: Another thing, do you want to make the full app in potrait mode?

Comment: No, I only want a viewController in portrait mode. Others viewControllers in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785766/set-landscape-orientation-for-ipad-only-not-iphone/20786308#20786308) might help you.

[Set Landscape Orientation for iPad Only NOT iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785766/set-landscape-orientation-for-ipad-only-not-iphone/20786308#20786308)