# Xcode No Choice of Devices in Deployment Info Section of Universal App

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, universal

Just completed converting my first iPhone-only app to a universal app.  Began work converting my second iPhone-only app that's been in the app store for some time to universal.  Changing Devices from iPhone to Universal under General/Deployment Info section of my target doesn't produce the iPhone and iPad selectors as it did in the first app I converted.  I've added a second storyboard and the Main storyboard file base name (iPad) = iPad property to my plist.  I need to use two storyboards, and need the iPhone/iPad selectors to appear.  I'm using Xcode v7.0. Sorry I can't post a screen shot, as my rep isn't high enough.

Answer (score 11):

In the PBXProject section of project.pbxproj file, there are lines looks like:

```
        TargetAttributes = {
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX = {
                CreatedOnToolsVersion = 7.1;
            };
        };
```

If this attribute exists in the project, the Xcode will not display "iPhone" and "iPad" buttons . Just remove these lines, then the buttons will show.

[Xcode 6.1 different "deployment info" section for duplicated target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793871/xcode-6-1-different-deployment-info-section-for-duplicated-target)

Comment: great help, how did you find out

Comment: This is still happening in Xcode 10.1 (10B61) :( but the fix still works! @Cheesehead1957 you should mark this as the accepted answer!